# Simulate with dymola python package not possible - dsres.mat not found

Tags: python, modelica, dymola

I tried simulating a simple model of my library with the use of python:

```
dymola.translateModel("path.to.model")

output = dymola.simulateExtendedModel('path.to.model')
log = dymola.getLastErrorLog()
print(log)
print(output)
```

Output is:

Translate = True

output =

```
Failed
Not possible to open file "dsres.mat": No such file or directory
 = false, {}

[False, []]
```

Seems like the model gets translated just fine, but doesn't finish/start simulating.

**Edit:**

- Licence status is correct
- Using DymolaInterface(showwindow=False) shows that the correct model and all its dependecies have been loaded
- Quite a lot of warnings (F.e. wrong unit used), but the model simulates just fine with dymola

Error Message:

[image]

Also:
I'm using `Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource(modelica://ProjectFolder/Data/Files/file.csv)` to load some files to the model.

**Edit2:**

- In the project I have two packages one with all of the models used in the simulations and one for the models that actually get simulated.
- Simulating checkmodels from the first package with the base models works fine.
- Moving the content from the second package in the first doesnt help same errors
- Simulating the real models doesn't work. Why does simulating models in the second package doesn't work?

Comment: There is some documentation at `file:///C:/Program%20Files/Dymola%202019%20FD01/Modelica/Library/python_interface/doc/index.html` and it includes examples. Do these work for you? Also, it would be easier to help you if your example above would be complete, i.e. including import statements, using a model from MSL instead of path.to.model etc.

Comment: Simulation with MSL work! Will edit my question on monday..

Comment: Does the simulation of this model work in normal Dymola? Is there a reason you use two different kinds of quotes (" and ')?

Comment: Works in dymola. No I used example code to get to this point that used ' instead of ". Pretty sure this isn't an issue. Something important myight be that small models simulate with this code, but more complex models don't!

Comment: Python supports both single and double quotes for strings, so this can not be the issue. It sounds like your Dymola started from Python is missing a license. Start Dymola windowed with `dymola = DymolaInterface(showwindow=True)` and check it in the GUI or use the function `RequestOption("Standard")`.

Comment: A function for checking the current license status from Python would be a usefull addition to the API !!

Comment: Since Dymola 2018 FD01 you can do that with the mentioned function `RequestOption()`, which is available as python function and inside Dymola in the DymolaCommands library.

Comment: Still haven't figured this one out. Translation works and licence status is fine.

Comment: Does Dymola simulate, is your computer busy for a while? Is it just the result file that is not found? What is the current working directory, before and after simulation? Did you have sucess with showwindow=True?

Comment: Before and after: C:/Users/User/Documents/SimResults
No showwindow=True doesnt simulate due to the same reasons. Also if I start Dymola manually and simulate the model the cd is the same.

Comment: So when you open everything manually and simulate, it works, but if you open and simulate from the script with showwindow=True it fails!? Then the GUI should show some additional error messages. Please post those also. Also, from your description it is not clear whether simulation starts (and then fails), or does not start at all.

Comment: Simulation doesn't start. Added an img from the error message.Please check out the new edit.

Comment: Try to create a minimal example and post it here. With the current information it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue:

Since the libary I use loads other libaries beforehand EnvironmentVariables had to be set during load up:

```
model.executeCommand('Modelica.Utilities.System.setEnvironmentVariable("{}", "{}");'
                               .format("startupscript",repopath + "/libaryXY.mos"))
```

Those environment variables were set in the load.mos script I use when I open Dymola without Python.

Without those, Dymola can't find the necessary csv files.

Comment: Well, this was impossible for us to know with the given information.

Comment: true and I would have included it if I had known. I just forgot to check the loadscript..